# how to plot the results of a (no, sometimes, yes) rubric to compare students performance pre and post instruction

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
`structure(list(Phase = c("Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", 
"Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", 
"Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction"
), Group = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", 
"G1", "G1"), Speaker = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", 
"S7", "S8", "S9", "S10"), Clarity = c("Sometimes", "Sometimes", 
"Sometimes", "Sometimes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Sometimes", "No", 
"Yes"), Loudness = c("Yes", "No", "Sometimes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), Details = c("sometimes ", "Sometimes ", 
"Sometimes ", "No", "No", "Yes", "sometimes ", "No", "No", "Yes"
), Eye_Contact = c("Sometimes", "No", "No", "No", "Sometimes", 
"Sometimes", "No", "No", "No", "Sometimes"), Interaction = c("Sometimes", 
"Sometimes ", "Yes", "No", "Sometimes ", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", 
"Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")`
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work. I want to compare each variable seperately but it combines all and the plot doesn't make sense.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
```

```
mydata <- read.csv("./R1_stat.csv")
#
mydata %>%
    gather(Phase, Clarity) %>%
    mutate(Clarity = factor(Clarity, levels = c("No", "Sometimes", "Yes"))) %>%
    mutate(Phase = factor(Phase, levels = c("Pre_instruction", "Post_instructions"))) %>%
    count(Phase, Clarity) %>%
    complete(Phase, Clarity, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    group_by(Phase) %>%
    mutate(Percentage = n / sum(n) * 100) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= Clarity, Percentage, fill= Phase))+ geom_histogram(stat='identity')
ggsave("2.png")
```

Comment: For reproducibility, please edit the question to include a sample of the data, rather than an image. You can paste the output of `dput(head(mydata, 10))`.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong when you run the code you shared? If there's an error message, sharing that will help with troubleshooting.

Comment: I want to compare each variable seperately but it combines all and the plot doesn't make sense @Seth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your x-axis contains category levels (the `Clarity` variable), you may find `geom_col` works well. In the edited question you note you hope to see each variable separately, but its not 100% clear to me:

1. Which variable(s) should be separated?
2. Separate as in different panels/plots or separate as in "not stacked up"?

The slice of data you shared doesn't contain any "Post_instruction" data, so I made some up just for the purpose of demonstration/visualization.

In the chart below I've plotted Clarity on the x-axis and Percentage on the y, as in your shared code. In `geom_col` you'll see the position has been dodged, so the different levels of your `fill` aesthetic (`Phase`) are next to each other.

Let me know if this isn't what you had in mind, and if possible please try and share a sketch or other example of what you hope to achieve.

```r
library(tidyverse)


mydata <- structure(list(Phase = c("Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", 
                                   "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", 
                                   "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", "Pre_instruction", 
                                   "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", 
                                   "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction", 
                                   "Post_instruction", "Post_instruction"), Clarity = c("Sometimes", 
                                                                                        "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Sometimes", 
                                                                                        "No", "Yes", "No", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "No", 
                                                                                        "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

mydata %>%
  mutate(Phase = factor(Phase, levels = c('Pre_instruction', 'Post_instruction')),
         Clarity = factor(Clarity, levels = c('No', 'Sometimes', 'Yes'))) %>%
  count(Phase, Clarity)%>%
  complete(Phase, Clarity, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Phase) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = scales::percent(n/sum(n))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Clarity, Percentage, fill = Phase)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>